# Is there any way to trigger auto fill in a web view in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, web, view

We have an app that uses this package https://pub.dev/packages/oauth_webauth in order to authenticate users. How can we trigger the auto fill in both iOS and android? Take in count that we cannot create the association files for those as we are using an external idp

We’be tried to hardcode the json files for app association but, didn’t work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.